# Word orders for ... is ... in

Tags: word-order

Are the following sentences both grammatical (under the intended sense)?

> "Hello" is "aloha" in Hawaiian.
>
> "Aloha" is "hello" in Hawaiian.

Comment: They're grammatical, but the possibility of the association of 'in Hawaiian' with either the first or second argument means that a rephrase might well be preferable in related cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think they're both grammatical, and mean the same thing. However, the reader has to be familiar with Hawaiian and English to understand the meaning, which makes the sentence moot. It would be better to rephrase it:

> "Aloha" means "hello" in Hawaiian.
>
> The Hawaiian word for "hello" is "aloha".
>
> "Aloha" is Hawaiian for "hello".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and have the same meaning, but there is a subtle difference between these two sentences.

In *"Aloha" is "hello" in Hawaiian.* the emphasis is the subject "Aloha" and it is the most common way to say it, mainly because you could say *"Aloha" **means** "hello" in Hawaiian* (as said by @Barmar).

However, I don't agree with him on using the third rephrased sentence *"Aloha" is Hawaiian for "hello".* - In my opinion is better to use one of your suggestions, since it is more common and direct.